# PHP - Find latest file based on filename pattern

Tags: php, regex, filenames

I have a bunch of gamers data. The data is stored as json with filename pattern as `gamerid_date_time_seed.json`. Eg below:

```
8841-2018-05-03-09-56-14-2118-data.json
8841-2018-05-03-10-50-22-1568-data.json
8841-2018-05-04-04-36-51-6081-data.json
8841-2018-05-04-06-56-50-1100-data.json
```

In the first filename for example, `2018-05-03-09-56-14` is the  `year-month-date-hour-min-sec` format. `8841`  is the gamer id and the last 4 digits, `2118` in this case is a seed value that can be ignored.

How can I parse this so that I get only the latest data file of a gamer? (In this case 8841-2018-05-04-06-56-50-1100-data.json) The issue is that sometimes a gamer might have multiple files but for same day.

I am not very good with regular expressions and stuff so I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: You can use `explode("-", $fileName)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: How are you storing the list of files?

Comment: @D.Kendall - list of files are in a local drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [glob](http://php.net/glob) function to get an array of files, and reverse sort to get the newest file as the first item in your array.

```
$gamerid = 8441;
$files = glob("filepath/".$gamerid."-*.json");
rsort($files);
$newestFile = $files[0];
```

Comment: And using a variable for the gamer id would allow grabbing the newest for whoever you need.

Comment: Edited my post, as suggested by @D.Kendall